# How Do I Store Words as Keys in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

Using a TreeMap, how would I use a comparator to map keys which are words to corresponding linked lists.

```
TreeMap<String, LinkedList<String>()> () words = new TreeMap(<Comparator> );
```

Is there a specific comparator I can use or do I have to implement a way for it to alphabetically sort the words I add to the TreeMap?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; by default `TreeMap` uses natural ordering as indicated in its docs, i.e., `compareTo`. Strings already implement `compareTo`.

Comment: Try to use it  TreeMap words = new TreeMap<String, LinkedList<String>>(Comparator.naturalOrder());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

As a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) promises to keep its keys sorted.

And [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class, the class of your map’s keys, already implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). So string objects know how to be sorted. With keys that are `Comparable`, you need not specify a `Comparator`.

Also, generally best to declare your collection in a more general way using interfaces or superclasses. This leaves room for you to change your concrete classes later without breaking other code. So `NavigableMap< String , List< String > > map` rather than `TreeMap< String , LinkedList< String > > map`.

For example, in code below we are free to use `List.of` to produce a `List` of some unknown concrete class rather than being limited to only `LinkedList` as seen in your code.

```
NavigableMap< String , List< String > > map = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Example usage.

```
map.put( "animals" , List.of( "dog" , "cat" , "bird" ) ) ;
map.put( "people" , List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" ) ) ;
map.put( "cars" , List.of( "Honda" , "Mazda" ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JYbHcO).

> map.toString() ➡ {animals=[dog, cat, bird], cars=[Honda, Mazda], people=[Alice, Bob, Carol]}

Note how the `"cars"` entry has been sorted from 3rd-added to the 2nd position, between "animals" and "people" alphabetically.